# Not Able to Compile When Mixing In A Trait When Using TableDrivenPropertyChecks

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am having trouble compiling the following code.

I am using TableDrivenPropertyChecks and I have something like this

```
trait MyTrait{

def foo: String

}

  "A X" should "do something correctly" in new MyTrait {

    val items =
      Table(
        "id",
          "1"
      )

    forAll(items) { item =>
      val foo = item
      //test condition
    }
}
```

The code fails with this message:

> Object creation impossible since member value foo:String in MyTrait is not defined.

How can I fix this? If I put the `override val foo outside the forAll` with an arbitrary string it compiles e.g

```
  "A X" should "do something correctly" in new MyTrait {


val items =
  Table(
    "id",
      "1"
  )
override val foo = "1"  //compiles

forAll(items) { item =>

  //test condition
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have fixed this by doing this

```
      "A X" should "do something correctly" in {  // take out the new MyTrait here


    val items =
      Table(
        "id",
          "1"
      )

    forAll(items) { item =>
      new MyTrait {  //create my trait here
            override val value = item
      //test condition
}
      }
    }
```

But I would like to know why it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original example fails to compile due to scoping. If you create `new MyTrait` on the top scope, but define `val foo = item` inside the loop, then that val is just a local variable inside the closure. It's quite logical if you think about it, a single instance of `MyTrait` cannot possibly have multiple implementations of the same property. In your solution you create multiple instances of `MyTrait` and each of them gets a single, stable implementation of `value`.